# Unable to Post json data to a remote server using phonegap and ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cordova

I am trying to send a json data from a javascript function running on a mobile data(phonegap framework) to a remote server. The code looks like below

```js
function sendJSONtoServer() {
  //alert("the call start was success to sendJSONtoServer");
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://myserver.edu/~sas0090/save-userinfo.php',
   data: {'message' : "Hey Hi"},
   type: 'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   crossDomain: true,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data) {
   //it works, do something with the data
   alert('Your comment was successfully added');
   },
   error: function() {
   //something went wrong, handle the error and display a message
   alert('There was an error adding your comment');
   }
  });
  alert("the call end was success to sendJSONtoServer");
}
```

I have researched that the same origin policy is not an issue here and most of the folks are able to get through this

http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/
http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/

Note: I am connected to the remote server though vpn network. Could this be an issue.
Also I am unable to get the failure message which are a part of the error: function() in AJAX

Any help will be highy appreciated.

Comment: You don't use POST method? I think `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` is not require since you mention `dataType` attribute. If every thing fine. I am curios about ~ symbol in your url. And more detailed debug, Please print error function `arguments`.

Comment: I  tried removing the contentType but to no luck. Also regarding '~' character, I have a remote server and its has got a home directory for my login. Also my home directory has got public_html which is used to place my php file. So I access the pages as http://myserver.edu/~mylogin/try.php

Answer (score 0):

Check `<meta>` tag with `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` parameter  in index.html file. Make appropriate(whitelist your domain) changes.

This may help  ["No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found." error in my phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212306/no-content-security-policy-meta-tag-found-error-in-my-phonegap-application)

Answer (score 0):

If its php add this to the begining of the server side script to avoid the same origin policy message.

```
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
     }   

     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
     exit(0);
     }
```